# How do I convert this to use a text file instead?

Tags: batch-file, text-files, delete-file

I would like to use a different method for me to whitelist my files from being deleted from a folder.

The concept would be to add the file names into a text file to keep it from being deleted. How do I accomplish this? So far this is what I have. I just don't want to go through all the brackets in the future:

```
for %%i in ("universe\*.world") do (

if /i not "%%~nxi"=="alpha_-47760677_13528428_3442937_2_8.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="alpha_-91359870_-23985140_-2679670_4_2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="beta_-10_-18_-22519438_9.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="alpha_71479806_30568958_-29806832_11_4.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="alpha_49727000_-95701173_-4914589_9.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="gamma_-98261021_73451017_-13446340_2_5.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
del /q "%%i"

)))))))))))))
)
```

Lets say the text file I want to  pull the list from is whitelist.txt, and each line has the file name I am keeping:

```
alpha_-47760677_13528428_3442937_2_8.world
alpha_-91359870_-23985140_-2679670_4_2.world
beta_-10_-18_-22519438_9.world
alpha_71479806_30568958_-29806832_11_4.world
alpha_49727000_-95701173_-4914589_9.world
gamma_-98261021_73451017_-13446340_2_5.world
```

Or maybe even without adding ".world" extension?

I've tried using this but when it's looking for files not to delete, it gets cut off due to "File not found - C:\Program" due to the nature of the space in Program Files (x86) having spaces:

```
for /f %%i in ("whitelist.txt") do attrib +r %%i & del /q "universe\*.world" & for /f %%i in ("whitelist.txt") do attrib -r %%i
```

Comment: put your path into parantheses: `"C:\path with spaces"`. Eventally replace `attrib -r %%i` with `attrib -r "%%i"`

Comment: "in was unexpected at this time" adding the parenthesis gave me this instead.

Comment: Even when I fixed it correctly, it seems to not even want to delete XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (".\*.world") DO (
  TYPE q20769624.txt|FINDSTR /i /b /e /L /c:"%%~ni"  >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO DEL "%%i"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Where `q20769624.txt` is your whitelist file, without the `.world` appendix.

This batch will simply `echo` the files to delete. Remove the `ECHO` keyword before the `DEL` to activate the delete function after testing.

Amended to allow spaces in the filename and no newline at end of data file.

Comment: The absolute best answer! Thank you very much Magoo!

Comment: Actually I just ran into a weird issue. Do you have any idea why my gamma file is being deleted? Using the same coding above, but without the .world, it will dodge everything but the gamma file. Only when I put in the .world into the whitelist will it not be deleted.

Comment: Try using `/c:"%%~ni"`

Comment: Assuming `gamma` is the very last entry in the whitelist, I found I could make this fail by removing the the newline after the last line. Using the `type` method seemed to fix the problem. I could also make it fail for lines which had stray spaces at one end or the other of the data line. Easier to fix the data than the batch on that one...